# Laravel 4 Role Based Mass Assignment

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mass-assignment

Ive justed started using laravel and I am curious to know if laravel-4 offers role based mass assignment straight out of the box ?

I wish to allow some users access to those fields(via mass assignment), when editing/updating Information.

I believe Rails Active record has this feature.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first, :last, :email             # :default role
  attr_accessible :can_fire_missiles, :as => :admin # :admin role
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Laravel doesn't have the concept of "roles" out of the box. This may make for a good feature request.

You can, right now, define which fields are "hidden", which are "visible", and to your point, which are ["fillable"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L113) (mass assignable) and which are [not mass-assignable](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L120).

Comment: This would a great feature. The admin section of a site would need to keep using `Eloquent::unguard()` in order to get around this, which is not a very good solution, especially when multiple permission levels are needed (like for managers instead of admins, for example). Would be nice to get this functionality in natively!