# Laravel Mass Assignment for Admins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, roles, mass-assignment

I have an app with a Users table with columns: `id|name|email|is_admin`. I want admins to be able to set other users as admins.

In `models/User.php` I prevent mass-assignment with:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
```

[Laravel 4 Role Based Mass Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541364/laravel-4-role-based-mass-assignment) concludes that Laravel has no such feature.

My question is, **what is a viable work-around**? How can I allow only admins to update the column 'is_admin' in my database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend your User model to create an admin-only version without the mass-assignment protection.

In the new class, override the `$fillable` property:

```
class UnprotectedUser extends User
{
    protected $fillable = [<all fields>];
}
```

Then use the new model in your admin-specific code:

```
$user = UnprotectedUser::create($arrayOfAllFields);
```

Be sure to use the original class in as many places as possible so that you can continue to take advantage of the mass-assignment protection.

Comment: This is a great answer because it allows you to continue using the built in ::create() functionality for mass-assignment.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the following code:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
```

will prevent from `Mass-Assignment` which means that, someone can't use something like this:

```
User::create(['name' => 'xxx', 'email' =>'x@mail.com', 'is_admin' => 1]);
```

In this case, the `is_admin` field won't be updated but it's still possible do the same thing using something like this (it's not `Mass Assignment`):

```
$user = User::find($id); // Or $user = new User; (when creating a new user);
$user->name = 'xxx';
$user->email = 'x@mail.com';
$user->is_admin = 1;
$user->save();
```

So there will be no problem to update the `User` like this way.

Comment: I ultimately used this answer because it allowed more flexibility in the model. E.g. On update() I wanted to only modify the users password if a new one was passed in.